# Как правильно говорить: выпрямись или выпрямься?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно говорить: "выпрямись" или "выпрямься" (это слово ворд подчеркивает, но тем не менее я часто слышу в речи именно такую форму)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно говорить *"выпрямись"*. Второе слово - это какое-то просторечное словечко, которое не употребляется в литературной речи, а ещё я бы его без мягкого знака написал.

Answer (score 1):

Согласна с Вами, Валентин, но всё-таки мягкий знак после согласных перед -ся и на конце слова в глаголах повелительного наклонения необходим (кроме "ляг", конечно).

Comment: Очень верное замечание.